# S3 CORS errors never end

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I'm using S3 to upload images from the UI. I have an AMI with access key id/secret access key that only allow `putObject` and `getObject`. All `putObject` are called with `public-read` acl.

I have this CORS configuration in the S3 bucket:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://foo.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:5000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I keep getting these CORS errors:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://foo.s3.amazonaws.com/items/images/e75768-2018-0-26/roar-bomber.png.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://foo.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I am clearly allowing the proper origins so I have no idea why it keeps yelling at me. But what's worse is that it will work at times and then stop working again even after nothing has changed...

Using Chrome browser.

Comment: You are missing OPTION method in your config.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

AWS doesn't allow setting `OPTIONS` method as allowed method.
Following the guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors, check the part **AllowedMethod Element**.

---

Add `OPTIONS` method as allowed in your CORS configuration.

Preflight request uses OPTION method to check which methods are allowed for CORS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: `OPTIONS` not allowed in S3 CORS config. Get this error: `Found unsupported HTTP method in CORS config. Unsupported method is OPTIONS`. Pretty sure Amazon handles this themselves as they want full control over it, we just provide our public-facing CORS options.

Comment: Oh. I found this on docs:
`For a preflight request, if the request includes an Access-Control-Request-Headers header, verify that the CORSRule includes the AllowedHeader entries for each value in the Access-Control-Request-Headers header. `

Comment: Yes you're right, for a CORS setup there needs to be a preflight OPTIONS endpoint, however for AWS S3 they handle the preflight themselves. Thanks though! :)

Comment: Maybe in the second rule, you need to add the `<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>`

Comment: No worries, I've actually already solved this another way. Thumbs up for the help though.

Comment: @Lansana how about sharing?

Comment: @TacB0sS This was a while ago so I don't remember, but I think I moved the logic to the server side.